# Numbers in Nested list

Tags: numbering, lists

I want to be able to use number in my nested list, but its changing to alpha like in this [picture](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/1.png). I would like to appear as 1 then 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 instead of a,b,c.

Any help?

Comment: Your picture does not show a nested list, just a plain list

Comment: the picture link is dead.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to customise lists. To achieve list numbering as you ask, use

```
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
```

to begin each of your lists.

Here is an example of such a nested list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Here is some document text.
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
    \item First subitem
    \item Second subitem
    \item Third subitem
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Perhaps you could expand your answer with a complete sample document showing a nested list.

Comment: Instead of adding `[label*=\arabic*.]` to every `enumerate` environment, you can make it global by adding `\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}` in the preamble.